Render ngrx-quill without editor
I have used ngx-quill to save data. The data gets stored as object with the required attributes. Example: {"ops":[{"attributes":{"size":"huge"},"insert":"hello"},{"insert":"\n"}]}
I want to render this as HTML directly inside say any div (not ngx-quill). Is there any parser available or some library?
I tried searching but could not find one. I tried using quill-view and quill-view-html but they did not work.
